# Germany - spousal liability for suicide

Tags: germany, suicide

Trigger warning - suicide. This is a throwaway account, because.

I have a long term illness that is going to kill me in a nasty way - not in the next 5 to 10 years, but eventually.

I live in Germany and I am married to a German. We have laws here requiring you to render assistance. Recently (in the last 5 years) we had a case where people stepped over a 'passed out' homeless person in a bank lobby who died (or was already dead). The court (quite rightly) found them guilty of neglecting their duty of care. They should at least have called the emergency services. This is a basic requirement of law.

My question is about how this law applies to a spouse.

Eventually, when it is my time to go, I do not want to wait out my disease but would rather pick a time and place of my choosing. Under this law, does my spouse live under the same threat? Do I need to hide this from her, or can I let her know of my intent? If she is there and present to the end, does she risk prosecution if she does nothing to stop it?

This is not a question about assisted dying laws in Germany (which I know a bit about), but simply about spousal liability about knowing what is going on.

In the spirit of this stack answers about other jurisdictions are welcome, but only answers about Germany are liable to be selected.

Comment: If your view is measured in a decade or more, note that the German law and case law on assisted suicide has been changing, and might change in the coming years. Right now a spouse would not be punished for assisting. Do you believe that the conditions for assisted suicide will not (yet) apply when you make your decision?

Comment: @o.m. He specifically excludes _assisted dying laws_. I would not be too sure about favorable changes, considering the Third Reich atrocities (e. g. „Aktion T4“). I think it’s important nevertheless to make an assessment _today_ so you can plan some wonderful _ⅹ years together with your partner of choice_, especially if the illness in question is associated with deteriorating health.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt, I was trying to understand the context of the question. If §217 is out of scope, what is it?

Comment: @o.m. Following the Constitutional Court’s decision of February 26, 2020, (file number 2 BvR 2347/15 and others) the current wording of § 217 is void, § 95 Ⅲ 1 BVerfGG. Discussing it is a can of worms. At any rate _aiding and abetting suicide_ is exempt of punishment nevertheless, because of the lack of a “main crime” (_Haupttat_): Killing yourself is not a crime. Dogmatic difficulties really arise when we’re within the realm of § 13. The attending doctor, or here the spouse, could be liable within §§ 212 Ⅰ, 13 StGB. This is the situation the former § 217 StGB intended to resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There are numerous what-ifs.
   Society’s moral values and thus laws may change.
   Or the unlikely death of your wife makes this question moot.
   (Let’s hope not.)
2. Yes, *failure to render assistance* is punishable under [§ 323c Ⅰ StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p3022).
   Everyone can commit this crime (*Allgemeindelikt*).
   However, this section concerns *accidents*, contingencies or other *unplanned* adverse events.
3. In your specific case there is *no element of “surprise”* though, quite the contrary.
   Your wife does not even need to be aware of the circumstances; the assessment “is there an accident” is made *objectively*.
4. Having said that, unfortunately there’s a difference of opinion how courts judge (case law) and how “legal scientists” (at *law school*) think.
   Ultimately it depends on what evidence investigators find.
5. Frankly, [§ 323c Ⅰ StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p3022) is a “minor issue” here.
   You can get *at most* “just” a one-year-sentence.
   And there’s the option to consider one’s own spouse’s death as *poena naturalis*, thus *refrain* from imposing any penalty because the grieving widow “won’t learn anything” from that, [§ 60 1 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p0414)←[§ 153b StPO](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stpo/englisch_stpo.html#p1348).
6. I’d worry more about §§ 211 ff. (murder, manslaughter, etc.):
   To *kill* someone means, a) any short‑term shortening of lifetime *through* action, or b) in the case of § 13 StGB, any *failure to potentially prolong* the lifetime.
   § 13 StGB, *Garantenstellung*, also applies to spouses, cf. § 1353 Ⅰ 2 BGB.

   - It *could* be argued that *failure* to take, say, a loaded firearm away from you constitutes manslaughter.
   - Or, worse, maybe you’re particularly wealthy and she’ll inherit your assets. This could be construed as *greed*, an aggravating circumstance.
7. At any rate it’s necessary that the omitted action *makes a difference*, i. e. prevents or at least inhibits the crime’s success (your death).
   At some point, with *terminally-ill* patients, you might say “he’ll die tomorrow anyway”.
   *Then* your wife could attend your suicide.
8. Finally, for a legally airtight plan I’d seriously consider to *change the jurisdiction* though, e. g. by going to Switzerland.
   Everything happening here is subject to German criminal law, § 3 StGB.

PS:
Marriage can be viewed as a kind of contract.
In principle you are *completely free* in formulating its terms.
However, you cannot make provisions concerning termination of life (*nichtdisponibles Rechtsgut*).

Comment: Having read your answer and trying to summarise it; it appears that yes; my wife would be liable for not rendering assistance, but then probably not punished too much for it?

Comment: As for the question of money; _we_ currently have enough money in _our_ shared bank account for _us_ to survive 10 years. There is no question of my spouse gaining money from my passing, only that she would be able to survive for some time in the future based on it.

Comment: Yes, I’m afraid _so far_ courts have considered suicide a “very unusual circumstance” thus similar to an accident. Yes, since the offender’s guilt forms the basis of the sentence, [§ 46 Ⅰ StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p0244), there would _potentially_ be a lenient sentence. Again, _future_, it’s like gazing into a crystal ball.
Assets comprises _all legal advantages_. For instance, if you have been paying contributions to the retirement fund, she will be entitled to a widow’s annuity, [§ 46 SGB Ⅵ](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/sgb_6/__46.html).